# Is there anyway to force a PDF to open/preview from a hyperlink within an email?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am sending an email that has a hyperlink to a PDF file stored in a content mgmt system.  When the end user receives the email and clicks on the link, the PDF file will 1) Open in Adobe, 2) Download, or 3) Ask which the user wants to do (based on their browser settings).

I want to force the PDF file to open in either Adobe (viewer, reader, acrobat... whatever the user has on their system); or open the PDF in a browser previewer (if there is one loaded with the user's default browser).  The ultimate goal:  Open the PDF without the user saving, even if they have "Save" as their default setting in the browser.

I've seen some programmatic ways to approach this, but being limited to what I can do in an email, I've not found any solutions.  I am currently using Outlook, but also have access to Thunderbird, and few other email clients.

I am creating the PDF's myself and have access to Adobe Acrobat XI Standard.  I've also been looking at ways to add javascript to the PDF itself which would cause it to open (and not download), but no luck so far.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: In a word... no.  And any email client or web browser which does this should never be used, as it poses a clear security problem.  Imagine a website which can force your computer to execute something (maybe an actual executable, maybe opening a malicious file with a newly discovered or otherwise unpatched exploit in the application) and then triggers a request to that file in the background without user interaction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done too much research into this so please take what I say with a grain of salt. I do not think what you are wanting to accomplish is possible considering that could pose security risks. If this is not true and it is possible, then I am sorry for leading anyone down a wrong path.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a huge security issue.